# How to preconfigure a SharePoint WebPart?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, web-parts

What is the best way to preconfigure a custom SharePoint WebPart?

Is it e.g. possible to add a textfile to the WSP package and simply read the file from the WebPart? I couldn't figure out a way to retrieve the path of the textfile after the deployment.

Or can I somehow add key value pairs to the .webpart file and access them from my WebPart?

Comment: could you add a custom config section to the web.config?

Comment: web.config is a terrible idea for your web part config data - there are much more appropriate places like the .wepbart file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema for .webpart files is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227561.aspx 
and allows for you to set default value properties for your WebPart.

Also, since you are running in the context of an assembly, you could read a file of config data from inside that assembly.  The first answer to this question shows you how:
[How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

Comment: I tried to add it to the properties section of the .webpart file. But how can I access the value from my WebPart code?